# Resizing User Control - anchor controls to center of form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control which consists of two controls and four buttons, arranged on a Form: the two controls are on the sides and the buttons in the middle in a vertical row.

When using the control in an app, I place it on a form.

Now, when re-sizing the form horizontally, the two controls just move left or right w/o changing their size.

What I need is that the controls stay anchored to the middle of the form and grow to the sides (sorry about the lack of clarity, I prepared screenshots but the site wouldn't let me attach them).

Is there a way to accomplish this without overriding the Resize event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems indeed that it cannot be done in the Designer, but here is the solution using overrides.
It works ok, except for some control flickering which I haven't been able to overcome.

```
public partial class SB : UserControl
{
    //variables to remember sizes and locations
    Size parentSize = new Size(0,0);
    Point parentLocation = new Point (0,0);
    ......
    // we care only for horizontal changes by dragging the left border;
    // all others take care of themselves by Designer code
    public void SB_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent == null)
            return;//we are still in the load process

        // get former values
        int fcsw = this.parentSize.Width;//former width
        int fclx = this.parentLocation.X;//former location

        Control control = (Control)sender;//this is our custom control

        // get present values
        int csw = control.Parent.Size.Width;//present width
        int clx = control.Parent.Location.X;//present location

        // both parent width and parent location have changed: it means we 
        // dragged the left border or one of the left corners
        if (csw != fcsw && clx != fclx)
        {
            int delta = clx - fclx;
            int lw = (int)this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0].Width;
            int nlw = lw - delta;
            if (nlw > 0)
            {
                this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0].Width -= delta;
            }
        }
        this.parentSize = control.Parent.Size;//always update it
        this.parentLocation = control.Parent.Location;
    }

    //contrary to documentation, the Resize event is not raised by moving
    //the form, so we have to override the Move event too, to update the
    //saved location
    private void SB_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent == null)
            return;//we are still in the load process
        this.parentSize = this.Parent.Size;//always update it
        this.parentLocation = this.Parent.Location;
    }
}
```

---

The above code works most of the time, but it fails for certain Move-Resize sequences. The solution is to respond to the Move and Resize events of the parent form (the consumer of the control), not of the control itself.

One more thing: due to the event firing order (Move first followed by Resize, had to move the working code from Resize() to Move(), which seems counterintuitive but it seems the right way nevertheless.

Comment: The ideal StackOverflow consists of a question and *one* answer.  Please learn to use the Edit feature to improve your posts instead of posting multiple responses in one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as base for your user control.
You need 3 columns and one row. The middle column needs to have a fixed size, and the other 2 you set to 50%. Not to worry, .Net is smart enough to calculate the percent they actually take.
Inside the right and left columns you put your controls and set the [`Dock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) property of both to `fill`. In the middle column you put a panel and set it's `Dock` property to `fill` as wall, and In that panel you put the buttons in the middle.
Set your table layout panel `Dock` to `fill` as well, and when adding the user control to the form use `Dock` `top`, `bottom` or `fill` as well.

Comment: To the OP, If you need more help with tablelayout, check out this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx

Comment: @Zohar Thanks, it works perfectly, except: 1: I would like the two side columns be re-size independently (as it is they maintain the 50% aspect ratio), 2: I would like the bottom two buttons to stick to the bottom (like the top buttons which stick to the top). Can it be done?

Comment: Can yoy upload some images to show exactly the behavior you want and leave a link in the comments?

Comment: I wanted to add images to my original question, but I was told that my rep is not high enough for that :-(

Comment: Just upload them some where and givea link...https://www.google.co.il/search?redir_esc=&client=ms-android-samsung&hl=iw-IL&oe=utf-8&safe=images&q=free+image+hosting&source=android-browser-suggest&qsubts=1430710016951

Comment: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/73dtrxmftym70g7/AAAfyYQZ83akEHIjqaoJUfQPa?dl=0)

Comment: So the right side should keep it's original size, while the left is growing? Your buttons can be set to the top and bottom of the panel that contains them using the respective `dock` property.

Comment: @Zohar, Fixed buttons OK. Now how do I make the two side panels to re-size independently?

Comment: If you want the right size to keep it's original size then just use a specific size in pixels for it's column. if you want it to resize at a different rate then the left one, you can specify a different percentage to it, although I'm not sure how this will look.

Comment: I want each side to resize independently i.e. left side keeps its original size while the right side is stretched and viceversa. It seems I'll have to override the Resize event.

Comment: @alexb How would you decide which size needs to keep it's original size and which should be stretched?

Comment: User grabs and stretches the right side: the right panel is stretched, the left side and the buttons in the middle stay put. Ditto for the left side. User grabs and stretches up or down: everything is re-sized (but this is already solved).

Comment: I see. I'll try to play with it tomorrow, but I'm not sure I can solve this without overriding the OnResize method.

Answer (score 0):

Erratum:
The above code works most of the time, but it fails for certain Move-Resize sequences. The solution is to respond to the Move and Resize events of the parent form (the consumer of the control), not of the control itself.
One more thing: due to the event firing order (Move first followed by Resize, had to move the working code from Resize() to Move(), which seems counterintuitive but it seems the right way nevertheless.

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be edited in your question.